# Generalization of the Central Limit Theorem for Local Martingales

Tags: convergence-divergence, martingales

the Central Limit Theorem for Local Martingales states the following.

**Theorem**
Let $M_n = (M_n(s))_{s \geq 0}$ be a square integrable local martingale such that for all $T > 0$ 
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[\sup_{0 \leq s \leq T}|\langle M_n\rangle_s - \langle M_n \rangle_{s-}|]=0$$
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[\sup_{0 \leq s \leq T}| M_n(s) -  M_n(s-)|^2]=0$$
and for all $s>0$ for $ n\rightarrow \infty$
$$ \langle M_n\rangle_s \rightarrow^\mathbb{P} cs$$
for some c>0. Than it holds
$$ M_n \rightarrow^d \sqrt{c}B.$$
for a Brownian Motion $B$.

**My question:** Is there some generalisation out there with a result like:

Let $M_n = (M(s))_{s \geq 0}$ be a square integrable local martingale such that for all $T > 0$ 
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[\sup_{0 \leq s \leq T}|\langle M_n\rangle_s - \langle M_n \rangle_{s-}|]=0$$
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[\sup_{0 \leq s \leq T}| M_n(s) -  M_n(s-)|^2]=0$$
and for all $s>0$ for $ n\rightarrow \infty$
$$ \langle M_n\rangle_s \rightarrow^\mathbb{P} \int_0^s\eta(u)du$$
$$ M_n \rightarrow^d \int\sqrt{\eta}dB.$$
for a Brownian Motion $B$ and $\eta \in \mathcal{L}^2$ (possible under stronger requirements than stated above). According to my intuition it should at least hold for a continuous, monton growing functions $\eta \in \mathcal{C}$.